# How to get dimensions of a custom UIView added via storyboard in initWithCoder:?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a custom UIView subclass that adds a subview programatically during initialisation.  I'm wanting this subview to be the same width as the custom UIView.

My code works *fine* if I *programatically* add the custom UIView.  However, when the UIView is initialised via the *StoryBoard*, I cannot obtain the custom UIView's width.

```
// Init programatically
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.frame.size.width);   //WILL return width
        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.bounds.size.width);  //WILL return width
    }
    return self;
}

// Init from storyboard
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.frame.size.width);   //Returns 0
        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.bounds.size.width);  //Returns 0
    }
    return self;
}
```

When initWithCoder: is run by StoryBoard, the UIView's frame and bounds are all returned as 0.
Is there any way of accessing the UIView's dimensions *within* initWithCoder??  Or, at least access the dimensions *before* drawRect: is called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than set the subviews dimensions in the init function, set it relative to the custom view in the layoutSubviews method of the custom view. Doing it here will mean that the width of the subview will also always change to match the width of the custom view even if you change the dimensions of the custom view at any point after initialisation.

Comment: Aaaah.  Thank you!  On testing you are indeed right.  layoutSubviews: had the dimensions available and is called before drawRect:!  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: To add a bit more explanation, if you're using Autolayout (which I think you are) then the bounds of the view controller's view and its subviews are not available until after layout has taken place - `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called on your view controller after this has happened.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-use your standard `initWithFrame` call.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        [self initWithFrame:[self frame]];

        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.frame.size.width);   
        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.bounds.size.width); 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: that's fine in a UIViewController, but not in a custom UIView subclass.  'self' already is a 'view' - ie there is no 'view' property for 'self' in UIView.

Comment: using your edited code, I get a compiler error `The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'`.

Comment: return [self initWithFrame:[self frame]]; or self = [self initWithFrame:[self frame]];

Comment: Using `self = [self initWithFrame:[self frame]];` results in the compiler complaining about breaking auto-layout constraints ('Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint') and results in unwanted layout.  I don't think IB has set the frame dimensions at the 'init' phase - which is the core of my problems.

Comment: once I use 'return' in initWithCoder:, the function is over.